# Adding numbers Conditionally

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, addition

This seems basic but I need to add numbers whether or not they are the condition is "on"  (i'll probably change this to boolean). So my question is how to do this in C code if it is possible. I tried something of this sort and various renditions:

```
    dfTotalTaxOwed[nIndex] = dfFedTaxOwed[nIndex]   + if(arrNYStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfNYStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}
                                                + if(arrNDStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfNDStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}
                                                + if(arrNHStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfNHStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}
                                                + if(arrOHStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfOHStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}
                                                + if(arrPAStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfPAStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}
                                                + if(arrNJStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfNJStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}
                                                + dfFicaTaxOwed[nIndex];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C control statements don't have return values so this approach won't work. Is there a reason you don't want to do a series of if statements like

```
if(arrNYStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1) {
    dfTotalTaxOwed[nIndex] += dfNYStateTaxOwed[nIndex];
}
```

?

Comment: well, the way I have the code set up is all state income taxes are computed then the if the state was "on" or not the it would add the needed taxes. So I suppose what you have there would work now that i think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#C).

`expr ? true value : false value`

I.e. replace `if(arrNYStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1){dfNYStateTaxOwed[nIndex];}` with `(arrNYStateTaxStatus[nIndex] == 1) ? dfNYStateTaxOwed[nIndex] : 0`.

On a side note, you might want to consider redesigning your program to use a dictionary instead of having an array for each state.